# Activate button on a component and continue counting until stopped

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to implement a timer.

My problem is this: I start the timer, but whenever I change the page, the timer is reset / I have to start it again :(

The goal is that when starting the timer it is only stopped when clicking pause, if I click start and can change page that the timer is always active.

Can anyone help me?

I leave below, the link of my example, the timer is in the service tab ... when I switch to home and return to service to view the time ... it is disabled, I intend it to always remain active

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i961jr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fservices%2Fservices.component.ts)

**html**

```
<button (click)='startTimer()'>Start Timer</button>
<button (click)='pauseTimer()'>Pause</button>

<p>{{display}}</p>
```

**component.ts**

```
startTimer() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
        if (this.time === 0) {
            this.time++;
        } else {
            this.time++;
        }
        this.display = this.transform(this.time)
    }, 1000);
}

transform(value: number): string {
    var sec_num = value;
    var hours = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600);
    var minutes = Math.floor((sec_num - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
    var seconds = sec_num - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);

    return hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
}

pauseTimer() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
}
```

Comment: It happens because everytime you switch between routes, your component gets destroyed.

Comment: And note that the time is still running. The component just doesn't display its value anymore, since it's destroyed. The new component starts and displays a new timer. Each time you navigate out of the component, you add a memory and CPU leak. Use a service.

Comment: you can put your Timer and timer logic into sigleton service

Comment: Does [this stackblitz help](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-evg22m?file=src%2Fapp%2Fservices%2Fservices.component.ts)? But I think you want the timer to continue rather than wait?

Comment: @NicholasK 
Exactly, I intend for him to continue counting time. Thanks for trying to help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this happens is because every time you switch between routes, your component gets destroyed. Now when you navigate to it again, a new timer is created along with other parts of your component.

To address the issue, delegate the computation of the timer-interval to a singleton service (`TimerService`) and inject it in your component.

timer.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class TimerService {
  interval;
  time = 0;
  display;

  startTimer() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (this.time === 0) {
        this.time++;
      } else {
        this.time++;
      }
      this.display = this.transform(this.time);

      return this.display;
    }, 1000);
  }

  transform(value: number): string {
    var sec_num = value;
    var hours = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600);
    var minutes = Math.floor((sec_num - hours * 3600) / 60);
    var seconds = sec_num - hours * 3600 - minutes * 60;
    return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
  }

  pauseTimer() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  fetchDisplay() {
    return this.display;
  }
}
```

services.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { TimerService } from "../timer.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-services",
  templateUrl: "./services.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./services.component.css"]
})
export class ServicesComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private timerService: TimerService) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  startTimer() {
    this.timerService.startTimer();
  }

  pauseTimer() {
    this.timerService.pauseTimer();
  }
}
```

services.component.html

```
<h1> Services Component </h1>

<button (click)='startTimer()'>Start Timer</button>
<button (click)='pauseTimer()'>Pause</button>

<p>{{ timerService.fetchDisplay() }}</p>
```

Working [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/singleton-timer)

Answer (score 1):

By using service you can persist data until you refresh the browser. I have gone through your code and added one helping service in services folder. don't get confused between service (which mean angular service) and services (your component services).
Just before you leave services component you need to update two variable in the angular service. one is whether timer is paused or not and another is timer count at that moment.
We *can do this in ngOnDestroy() life cycle hook of services component. When we come back to 
services component we will fetch past info from angular services and will display timer accordingly.

Below is piece of code.
in services folder add timer.service.ts file and write below code.

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TimerService {
  time:number = 0;
  timerState:any;
}
```

modify your services component to below.

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import {TimerService} from './timer.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-services',
  templateUrl: './services.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./services.component.css']
})
export class ServicesComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  constructor(private timerService: TimerService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.time = this.timerService.time;
    if(this.timerService.timerState === 'visible_on') {
      this.startTimer();
    } else if(this.timerService.timerState === 'visible_off'){
      this.display = this.transform(this.timerService.time);
    }
  }
interval;
  time = 0;
  display:any;

startTimer() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (this.time === 0) {
        this.time++;
      } else {
        this.time++;
      }
      this.display=this.transform( this.time);
      this.timerService.timerState = 'visible_on';
    }, 1000);
  }

      transform(value: number): string {
      var sec_num = value; 
    var hours   = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600);
    var minutes = Math.floor((sec_num - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
    var seconds = sec_num - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);

    return hours+':'+minutes+':'+seconds;
    }

  pauseTimer(data,row) {
    this.timerService.timerState = 'visible_off';
    clearInterval(this.interval);

  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.timerService.time = this.time;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help me! I tried to imply this, but time kept stopping. Can you put the stackblitz link or try to edit mine? It could be me applying something badly :(